# C++ Win32 send message by email or by web browser

Tags: c++, winapi, message

I dont know which way is easier so i ask for simplier one.
How to send email in win32 or open link like: www.wp.com/?text=message but dont show browser to user? Im new to win32, please help.

Comment: You could do the browser thing with `ShellExecute` combined with `SW_HIDE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use the WinHttp api to open the http url www.wp.com/?text=message. This will not open the browser and will send the email also. I assume that you have full control over administration of www.wp.com so that it can send email from the server.

See this for WinHttp help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383138%28VS.85%29.aspx